# Why is my session not being updated correctly after this ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a script which updates quantities of products in both a shoppingcart (in menu) and a shoppingcart page. It sort of works, but sometimes when I update the quantity, the correct amount is displayed in my hover menu but not on the cart page.

The same goes for deleting a product (but I won't include that script here since it is basically the same issue).

Sometimes if I delete a product from my hover menu, the product is still visible on my cartpage, only when I refresh the page the product is removed.

My shopping cart page has this code for the quantity:

```
session_start();
foreach($_SESSION['producten'] as $cart){
    <input name="quantity" id="'.$cart['productid'].$cart['kuubkosten'].'" value="'.$cart['quantity'].'" type="number" min="1">
}
```

Then with JS I do this:

```
  // Update cart quantities
  $('body').on('click', '.update_cart_btn', function(event) {
    // Stop default behaviour
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get the ID of the product
    var elements = $('input[name="quantity"]'),
    url = 'catalog/cart.php',
    url1 = 'catalog/cartpage.php',
    postBody = [];
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        var element = $(elements[i]);
        postBody.push({
            product: element.attr('id'),
            quantity: element.val()
        })
    }
    // Post above values to shoppingcart
    var posting = $.post( url, {quantityobject: JSON.stringify(postBody)} );
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        var content = $( data );
        $( "#shoppingcart" ).empty().append( content );
    });

    // Post to the cartpage
    var posting1 = $.post( url1, {quantityobject: JSON.stringify(postBody)} );
    posting1.done(function( data1 ) {
        var content1 = $( data1 );
        $( "#cartpage" ).empty().append( content1 );
    });
  });
```

Then in my first PHP script `('catalog/cart.php')` I do this (only part of code, of course I also get the new HTML with session data):

```
session_start();
if($_POST['quantityobject']){
    $quantityobject = $_POST['quantityobject'];

    $arrayquantity = json_decode($quantityobject);

    foreach ($arrayquantity as $object) {

        // Check if product exists in array
        if (isset($_SESSION['producten'][$object->product])) {
            // if so replace quantity with posted one
           $_SESSION['producten'][$object->product]['quantity'] = $object->quantity;
        }
    }
}
```

If I am correct it updates the session in `cart.php` and then moves on to request `cartpage.php` at which time the session has already been updated in the first call, so it should display the latest session data.

Sometimes it does but not always, as if ajax is moving to fast and my PHP script can't keep up? The thing is, it always works in the first script and only sometimes for both scripts.

What can I do about this?

If it helps anything this is what my session array looks like (example):

```
Array
(
    [3280|2 kuub] => Array
        (
            [productid] => 3
            [productname] => Eikenhout pallet
            [productalias] => eikenhout-pallet
            [productcat] => Eikenhout
            [productimage] => cms/images/catalogus/product.jpg
            [catalias] => eikenhout
            [price] => 150
            [quantity] => 1
            [kuubkosten] => 280|2 kuub
        )

    [3390|3 kuub] => Array
        (
            [productid] => 3
            [productname] => Eikenhout pallet
            [productalias] => eikenhout-pallet
            [productcat] => Eikenhout
            [productimage] => cms/images/catalogus/product.jpg
            [catalias] => eikenhout
            [price] => 150
            [quantity] => 4
            [kuubkosten] => 390|3 kuub
        )

    [35|4 kuub] => Array
        (
            [productid] => 3
            [productname] => Eikenhout pallet
            [productalias] => eikenhout-pallet
            [productcat] => Eikenhout
            [productimage] => cms/images/catalogus/product.jpg
            [catalias] => eikenhout
            [price] => 150
            [quantity] => 1
            [kuubkosten] => 5|4 kuub
        )

)
```

I have `session_start();` added everywhere.

Comment: Why have two PHPs? And if you must, put the call to one inside the done of the other: `var quantityobject = {quantityobject: JSON.stringify(postBody) }; posting = $.post( url, quantityobject);
posting.done(function( data ) {
        var content = $( data );
        $( "#shoppingcart" ).empty().append( content );
    /* Post to the cartpage */
    var posting1 = $.post( url1, quantityobject);
    posting1.done(function( data1 ) {
        var content1 = $( data1 );
        $( "#cartpage" ).empty().append( content1 );
    });`

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you made sure that the part where something is added to the session is really used?

Comment: @mplungjan Because I renew the HTML of both carts too. I return a loop of all products and append them to both divs.